# Gridview with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am searching for a example of gridview which has checkbox on each row and on header [Check ALL]. It should maintain the check on paging and when clicked on Check all it should check all the checkboxes on all the pages.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a template field, and in that template field use a header template:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.headertemplate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use template field for that...just do not mention any thing in header template and in item template use

```
<asp:CheckBox runat=server id=chkBox1>
```

For selection through page u must know the Column no of the grid where u r placing Check boxes

```
foreach (gridviewRow variable in gridview name.rows)
{
     // find the check box and set the Checked = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this javascript method

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function SelectAll(spanChk,grdClientID) {
       var IsChecked = spanChk.checked;
       var Chk = spanChk;
          Parent = document.getElementById(grdClientID);           
          var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');                          
          for(i=0;i<items.length;i++)
          {                
              if(items[i].type=="checkbox")
              {            
                        items[i].checked=document.getElementById(spanChk).checked;     
              }
          }     
    }
</script>
<HeaderTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkHeader" onclick="SelectAll('<%=chkHeader.ClientID %>, <%=yourGrid.ClientID %>') />
</HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: no, as this is javascript function, it will only check checkboxes that are rendered in the browser. Secondly it is not 100% possible to check  checkboxes of other page index.

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView templates to modify the layout of your grid view...

Refer to the following links for your case:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1473431/3418598.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20210728070916/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/053106-1.aspx